# Is there a way to concatenate a string parameter with observer next() method parameter?

Tags: angular, observable, concatenation

I have such a method:

```
public getContentForGivenFields(fields: any) {
    this.content$.subscribe({
      next: res => {
        console.log(res.fields); // res.first_name => {first_name object}
      }
    })
  }
```

And the 2nd method that calls the 1st one:

```
public getPersonName() {
    this.service.getContentForGivenFields("first_name");
  }
```

I want the first method to take its parameter and use it in the way that I showed above. If you know another way - please, share!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass few names and concatenate those fields? or just one property?
if one then `res[fieldName]`
otherwise `fields.map(field => res[field]).join(' ')` or sth similar;

or you can use `pluck` operator and then concatenate result